# How do I force Unity to reload editor scripts

Tags: unity

I am working of some editor scripts for Unity but have found that it is difficult to force Unity to reload my editor scripts.

My scripts are modelled on the [static constructor approach](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RunningEditorCodeOnLaunch.html) and perform some manipulation of the Tag Manager.

Currently the static constructor is called when either:

1. Unity is launched, or
2. Changes to a script (any of them) are written to disk

While verifying that the tag manipulation performed by the script is correct I am manually setting the tags via the GUI and then triggering script by saving a trivial change to the file.

This is clearly a clumsy workaround, is there a better way to force Unity to reload editor scripts?

Comment: Perhaps your situation is more complex, but normally I find that Unity will automatically reload any edited scripts if I switch to a different window and then switch back to Unity.